# Properties of submodular functions

Tags: optimization, matroids, combinatorial-designs

I was working on submodular set functions, and I came across a property on Wikipedia, that I was not able to prove/find any reference for. On the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submodular_set_function) on submodular set functions, Under the section Properties, The third property states that :

> More generally, $g(S) = h(f(S))$ is submodular, for any non decreasing concave function $h$.

They claim that this is true for all submodular $f(S)$. Is there a reference for this property where I will be able to find a proof? Alternatively, is there is a simple proof for this that I may be missing?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that in the previous sentence, they mention the fact that it has to be a Monotone submodular function. Indeed, if you use $f$ as a graph cut function, which is non-monotone, and a concave mapping for example $\sqrt{.}$ then it will no longer be submodular. (This is also pointed out as a comment by Chris Harshaw in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411635/submodular-function-square-of-which-is-also-submodular)).

Let $\phi: \mathfrak{D} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a concave mapping where $\mathfrak{D}$ is the domain of $\phi$. Let s, t, and u be such that $s < t < u $, then we can show the following for concave functions.

$$ \frac{\phi(t)- \phi(s)}{t - s} \geq \frac{\phi(u)-\phi(s)}{u - s} \geq \frac{\phi(u)-\phi(t)}{u - t}$$

Now consider a, b, c, and d such that $a < b < c < d$. Then we have the following using the above-mentioned property.

$$ \frac{\phi(c)- \phi(a)}{c - a} \geq \frac{\phi(d)-\phi(b)}{d - b} $$

Moreover, we also have

$$ \frac{\phi(b)- \phi(a)}{b - a} \geq \frac{\phi(d)-\phi(c)}{d - c} $$

Let $A \subset B \subset V$ and $ e \in V \setminus B$. From monotonicity of $f$, we have $ f(A) \lt f(A \cup \{e\}) $ and $ f(B) \lt f(B \cup \{e\}) $. Moreover, $f(A) \lt f(B)$ and $f(A \cup \{e\}) \lt f(B \cup \{e\})$. Thus, we have two possible scenarios

$$f(A) \lt f(B) \lt f(A \cup \{e\}) \lt f(B \cup \{e\})$$ and
$$f(A) \lt f(A \cup \{e\}) \lt f(B)  \lt f(B \cup \{e\})$$

Denote $g(S) = \phi(f(S))$ and the corresponding "gain" as $g(e | A) = g(A \cup \{e\}) - g(A) $. With these notations, and the property of concave functions, we can show that

$$ \frac{g(e|A)}{f(e|A)} \geq  \frac{g(e|B)}{f(e|B)} $$
Therefore,
$$ g(e|A) \geq  g(e|B)\frac{f(e|A)}{f(e|B)} $$

Due to submodularity, we have $\frac{f(e|A)}{f(e|B)} \geq 1$.

Therefore we have diminishing return property for g as well. That is,
$\frac{g(e|A)}{g(e|B)} \geq 1$

Comment: This proof assumes that the domain of the concave function has some well defined ordering. This would imply, that this proof does not scale up for concave functions defined in higher dimensions. I do not think this property holds for such cases

Comment: Typically and as per the Wikipedia page to which your question is referring, the submodular set function is defined as a mapping from subsets of the ground set to Real numbers, where we can define ordering. While one may define a set function that output in R^n and may define coordinate wise submodularity (I do not know if there is a widely accepted notion of vector submodular function), neither the Wikipedia page, nor the question explicitly mention this fact, that is submodular function outputs in higher dimension space.

Answer (score 1):

Gantavya's answer is good, but I prefer my notation :-).

Suppose $f$ is monotone non decreasing & submodular, and $h$ is concave and non decreasing.

We prove that $h \circ f$ is submodular using the equivalent law of diminishing returns.

Suppose that $A \subset B $ and $i \notin B$.
Let $x_1 = f(A), x_2=f(A \cup \{i\}), y_1 = f(B), y_2 = f(B \cup \{i\})$.
Then we have (since $f$ is submodular) $x_2-x_1 \ge y_2 -y_1$. Also note that since $f$ is monotone non decreasing, $x_1 \le y_1$.

Let $\delta = y_2 - y_1$ , then we have
$h(x_1+\delta) -h(x_1) \ge h(y_1+\delta) -h(y_1) = h(y_2)-h(y_1)$
from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Functions_of_one_variable (noting that $-h$ is convex and $R(x_1+\delta,x_1) \ge R(y_1+\delta,y_1)$.)

Since $x_2 \ge x_1+\delta$ and $h$ is nondecreasing, $h(x_2) \ge h(x_1+\delta)$ and so we have
$(h \circ f)(A \cup \{i\}) - (h \circ f)(A) \ge (h \circ f)(B \cup \{i\}) - (h \circ f)(B \cup \{i\}) $ and so $h \circ f$ is submodular.